# Scroll-activated CSS animations via IntersectionObserver are not working properly in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I was trying to animate a webpage and considered using the scrolling function on a webpage to activate said animations. I was following a tutorial using JavaScript and no additional library to do this via the following code

```
function App() {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.classList.add("show");
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove("show");
      }
    });
  });

  const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
  hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="sample">Sample hello Text</p>
      <p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </p>
      <p className="hidden">Instruction 1</p>
      <p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </p>
      <p className="hidden">Instruction 2</p>
      <p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </p>
      <p className="hidden">Instruction 3</p>
      <p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </p>
      <div>
        <img className="hidden" src="src/assets/react.svg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note: This is just test code and the break tags were used, so there is content to scroll to.

Here is the accompanying CSS code:

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
div {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: bold;
  color: black;
}

.hidden {
  transition: all 1.5s;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(5px);

  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

/*
// Same animations but using keyframes and no additional code to execute upon scrolling, this works // perfectly
.hidden {
  transition: all 1.5s;
  transform: translate(-150%);
  animation: thing 1s linear both;
}
@keyframes thing {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150%);
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
} */
```

Now in the tutorial, they did this using an HTML and CSS file, but here I was doing this using React with Vite and Typescript. Now what happens is this:

[image: bugged animation]

The animation from `.hidden` to `.show`doeso not execute and it is stuck in the `.hidden` state, unless I save the `.tsx` file that holds the app function without editing anything. Upon refreshing the page the same issue would happen again and I needed to resave the file for it to work properly.

This is what it should look like after the animations execute:

[image: executed animation]

I also thought that since the text `Instruction1` and `Instruction2` was in view upon refresh that the animations would execute as they start off in the intersection, but it still suffered the same issue.

I reproduced the same code in a regular HTML and JS file and the code works. I redid the exact animations with keyframes without the intersectionObserver code and it works, but this meant that the animations just executed at the beginning of the page loading and not upon it being in view.

I edited the CSS file with the transformations targeting `.hidden` to see if it was the CSS file that was causing the errors but upon saving any changes the webpage updates correspondingly the `.hidden` state but the animation to go to `.show` won't happen unless again I save the `.tsx` file.

Does anyone know what is causing the issue, is it because it's Typescript or React or Vit,e and how to fix this?

Also what other ways are there to animate on scroll without the use of an external library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is not working because you are trying to observe the components before they are even rendered. Set the `IntersectionObserver` in a `useEffect`, like so:

```js
function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          entry.target.classList.add("show");
        } else {
          entry.target.classList.remove("show");
        }
      });
    });

    const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
    hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));
    
    // Clean up the memory before the component gets destroyed:
    return () => {
      hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.unobserve(el));
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="sample">Scroll to see annimations</p>
      <p className="hidden">Instruction 1</p>
      <p className="hidden">Instruction 2</p>
      <p className="hidden">Instruction 3</p>
    </div>
  );
}

// This is to have a working example here on Stack Overflow:
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

p {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
p:first-of-type {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.hidden {
  transition: all 1.5s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!-- This is to have a working example here on Stack Overflow: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am not very well knowledgeable about the DOM and such but if the components were observed before they were rendered then wouldn't they already be in the .show state and the animation would carry out making them unblurred and in translateX(0) and fully opaque instead of in the .hidden state?

Comment: Actually non. Without the `useEffect`, as you did, `document.querySelectorAll(".hidden")` would return an empty array, because the body of the component runs before the JSX is rendred.